# Splitting up regex pattern restriction in XSD

Tags: regex, xml, validation, xsd

I have a regex pattern in my XSD that does the trick but the readability is poor.

```
<xs:element name="short_description">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:pattern value="|^([a-zA-Z0-9áÁâÂàÀäÄåÅöÖòÒóÓôÔøØüÜûÛùÙúÚßíÍïÏîÎìÌñÑÇç.,?()!\/çéÉêÊèÈëË +;&amp;&apos;':&quot;\n\t%#£°€@=«»¦*`´-]){1,}$"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Therefore I tried to seperate it as the following for a better readability (example)

```
    <xs:element name="title">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <!-- Check the title with no limitation to size -->
                <xs:pattern value="|^([a-zA-Z0-9áÁâÂàÀäÄåÅöÖòÒóÓôÔøØüÜûÛùÙúÚßíÍïÏîÎìÌñÑÇçéÉêÊèÈëË]){1,}$"/>
                <xs:pattern value="|^([.,?()!\/ +;':`´-]){1,}$"/>
                <xs:pattern value="|^([&amp;$apos;&quot;]){1,}$"/>
                <xs:pattern value="|^([\n\t]){1,}$"/>
                <xs:pattern value="|^([%#£°€@=«»¦*]){1,}$"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
```

After rerunning my XSD it seems that he is only looking at the first line when the patterns are separated.

Is there a way to make the first pattern (see above) more readable? Or am I doing something wrong in the second example?

Comment: Are you sure your patterns work? What is the first one supposed to do? What does `$apos;` stand for? Did you mean `&apos;`? Looks like you need to use 1 regex, [`"[a-zA-Z0-9áÁâÂàÀäÄåÅöÖòÒóÓôÔøØüÜûÛùÙúÚßíÍïÏîÎìÌñÑÇç.,?()!/çéÉêÊèÈëË +;&amp;&apos;:&quot;\n\t%#£°€@=«»¦*\`´-]+"`](https://regex101.com/r/GiXSXy/1) since breaking it into separate ones  is just not the same.

Comment: Yes, they work and indeed, it had to be &apos;.

But maybe we should leave out the question if it works or not ;) make it more general. If you have such a regex, can you separate it into multiple lines?

Comment: You cannot just split `[^a-z0-9]` into `[^a-z]|[^0-9]`. It breaks the whole functionality and matches any char.

Comment: Oke understood, no splitting up of regex :-). One more question though. In your first comment, you basically changed '|^([...])$' into '[...]+'. Why is that?

Comment: Well, at least not the character classes, and certainly not XML Schema ones. XML Schema regex patterns are anchored *always*. You need no `^` and `$`, these anchors are redundant. To match a value containing `3`, you need to write `".*3.*"`. No idea what you mean by `|` - the value may be empty? It is best to use an optional group - `"(MY_PATTERN)?"`.

Comment: The following regex did the trick `([a-zA-Z0-9áÁâÂàÀäÄåÅöÖòÒóÓôÔøØüÜûÛùÙúÚßíÍïÏîÎìÌñÑÇç.,?()!/çéÉêÊèÈëË +;&amp;&apos;:&quot;\n\t%#£$°€@=«»¦*-]+)?`. Thanks man!

Comment: I added some more explanation. The multiple patterns are not ignored, they are just parsed in a specific way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [**multiple patterns**](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/CR-xmlschema11-2-20110721/datatypes.html#rf-pattern), but the relationship between them is that of OR, not AND:

> An XML `<restriction>` containing more than one `<pattern>` element gives rise to a single ·regular expression· in the set; this regular expression is an "or" of the ·regular expressions· that are the content of the `<pattern>` elements.

If you have `[A-Za-z]+` and then `[0-9]+`, it means that you allow values that only consist of 1 or more letters (the first one) or of 1+ digits (the second). It does not mean you allow a string consisting of 1 or more letters or digits.

It is safer in this case to write the pattern as a single restriction:

```
<xs:pattern value="([a-zA-Z0-9áÁâÂàÀäÄåÅöÖòÒóÓôÔøØüÜûÛùÙúÚßíÍïÏîÎìÌñÑÇç.,?()!/çéÉêÊèÈëË +;&amp;&apos;:&quot;\n\t%#£°€@=«»¦*`´-]+)?" />
```

Note that:

- To make a pattern optional (i.e. allow an empty match) it is safer to enclose the whole pattern with an optional group (`(<PATTERN>)?`)
- `$apos;` should be `&apos;`
- XML Schema regexps are anchored by default, `^` and `$` should not be used
- To support Unicode letters, you may consider just using `\p{L}` Unicode category class.

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated

Comment: I wish I could but I don't have enough reputation points to upvote (I need 15, so 5 remaining)

Comment: Done, thanks! One more question though. This `\p{L}` sounds very interesting but I can't find good examples of how to implement them in my regex. I tried `([\p{L}]+)?` but with no success.

Comment: It is called [*category escape `\p{X}`*](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dt-ccescat). `\p{L}` stands for any Unicode letter. Your regex is more complex, you need to add all other supported chars, other than letters, into the `[....]`.

Comment: Aaah, now I see it. I just had to add more categories. For example: `([\p{L}\p{Z}]+)?`. I will check the link you put to see which categories I can use as well. Wow, thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

It is permitted to have multiple pattern facets: if you do so, the input must match any one of them. (That's slightly counter-intuitive since normally each facet defines a restrictive rule and you have to satisfy all of them.)

`^` and `$` are not meta-characters in XSD: they match themselves. So I can't see how any of your patterns can possibly work. (Unless the schema processor is non-conformant, which sadly is sometimes the case.)

Since your `[a-zA-Z0-9...]` class includes most of Latin-1, you could consider using a subtraction: `[&#x20;-&#xff;-[exceptions]]`, where exceptions is the list of characters in Latin-1 that you want to exclude.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @WiktorStribiżew, I was able to find an answer.

1. It is not possible to split a regex in the XSD in the way that I'm using it
2. The regex also improved -> `([a-zA-Z0-9áÁâÂàÀäÄåÅöÖòÒóÓôÔøØüÜûÛùÙúÚßíÍïÏîÎìÌñÑÇç.,?()!/çéÉêÊèÈëË +;&amp;&apos;:&quot;\n\t%#£$°€@=«»¦*`´-]+)?`

-> This regex allows 1 to many characters

-> It also allows empty tags